# How to fill zero in vector at alternate position in R

Tags: r

I am new to R language. I came to a situation where I need to fill the zero at alternate Position in the vector. for Example:

```
v<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I need the new vector like

```
0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 8 0 9 0 10
```

I tried with for loop to fill the zero but I am not able to do.

Comment: Several answers [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Interleaving-elements-of-two-vectors-td795123.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of approaches

Create a vector of zeros and then replace the correct indices

```
x1 <- rep(0, length(x)*2)
x1[seq(2,20,by=2)] <- x
```

or use `Map` and `c`

```
 unlist(Map(c,0,x))
```

Comment: Dang less characters than my response +1

Comment: I don't think so. I get `18` for mine, `16` for yours

Comment: Yay back on top but now I've wasted extra key strokes with my comments :(

Comment: @ thanks mnel really your answer is helpful for me :)

Answer (score 8):

I am sure there are plenty of solutions, but

```
as.vector(rbind(0,v))
 [1]  0  1  0  2  0  3  0  4  0  5  0  6  0  7  0  8  0  9  0 10
```

will do it.

Comment: @thelatemail.. Thanks a lot its working fine. I like this approach very much it is very precise way though Tyler's answer is also precise both answer are good and useful for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks:

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
c(mapply(c, 0, v))
```